# Get first value of array returned by function

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to retrieve the first value of an array that is returned by a function without assigning the returned array to a temporary array.

```
function Return_Array as MyClass()
   Dim TmpArr() as Myclass
   'Fill TmpArr
   return_array = TmpArr
end function

sub Do_Something
   'things
   MyVar = MyConst + Return_Array()(0).MyMethod  'Works :)
   'More things
end sub

sub Do_Something_Bis
   'things
   Dim TmpArr() as Myclass
   TmpArr = Return_Array
   MyVar = MyConst + TmpArr(0).MyMethod  'Works but not as elegant
   'More things
end sub
```

Excpected result is : Return the first value in the Return_Array returned array.

Edit : Solved

Comment: `Return_Array` first off not `Retur_Array` also, think it will just be `Return_Array(0)`

Comment: You define Return_Array as type MyClass. Try returning a variant instead

Comment: `Return_Array()(0).MyMethod` works for me after I made the correction Nathan mentioned.

Comment: I'm going to pretend I haven't spent a lot of time searching why this didn't worked.